# How do you combine 2 similar if statements to shorten your python programming code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a python project and need to combine 2 similar if statements to shorten the length of my code.

Here is the selection of code I need to combine:

```
if value1 < 14:
    value1 = 10

if value2 < 14:
    value2 = 10
```

Can anyone please help me combine these 2 if statements?

Comment: I rolled back the original question, don't remove the question text to say it has been resolved. If you find an answer between those posted, just accept it (click on the tick near the votes number); if you find a solution by yourself, post it as a reply and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

You can factor out the logic

```
def fix_value(x):
    return 10 if x < 14 else x
```

then you can use it multiple times

```
value1 = fix_value(value1)
value2 = fix_value(value2)
value3 = fix_value(value3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine these. You are testing different things and you are doing different things within them.

...Not entirely true, you can totally combine them, but the ways of doing that are not nearly as clear as what you already have. If the code in your OP is actually what your code is, then factoring out the logic or mapping the logic is really overcomplicating what should just be what it is: Two if statements.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer. Can you please delete this answer so I can delete this question as it's a waste of a topic. Thanks :)

Comment: I personally don't see much sense in deleting it, but it will probably get closed. Perhaps accept an answer and move on.

Comment: -1 "but the ways of doing that are not nearly as clear as what you already have." I disagree, putting the logic into a function is a good idea most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this:

```
value1, value2 = map( lambda x: 10 if x < 14 else x, [value1, value2 ] )
```